# How can I differentiate between a boolean and a string return value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have a function that returns a value that can be true if the condition is met and false if not, but the function can also return a string message in case of an error.

I need to differentiate between the true/false boolean values under normal conditions without mistaking the string value for either one. My strategy is to use a `parseBoolean()` function that will return a true Boolean-typed true/false value when passed a boolean input, but a "falsy" value that isn't a Boolean-typed `false` when passed a string.

#### Example

```
function validate(kkk)
{
  //... some check that validates 
  return true;
  //... some check that doesn't validate
  return false;
  //... failure - return explanation
  return 'Error Message jjjjjjjj';
}

function usingit(data)
{
  if(parseBoolean(validate(data)) != false)
  {
    /// the value is Boolean true
  }
  else
  {
    if(parseBoolean(validate(data)) === false)
    {
      /// the value is Boolean false
    }
    else
    {
      /// the value is false but not of a Boolean type 
      /// so we will display it as the error message text.
    }
  }
}
```

...but I haven't figured out how to create a `parseBoolean()` function that behaves this way. Any ideas?

Comment: `if(!!'anystring' !== false)`

Comment: 1. I see you are using `!==` and not `==`. Be careful b/c a string will never ever `===` false, although it could `==` false if the string is empty.

Comment: I don't understand: the comments in your code imply that you want 'anystring' to be both true _and_ false.

Comment: @nnnnnn so it wasn't just me ? lol

Comment: Well, I supposed the OP just need some checker function. ) I'm simple, see. )

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do here?

Comment: @RegisteredUser You need to define what you want to be `true` and `false` before you can write this function. It could be, "I want FFF to be true and everything else to be false". But it needs to be defined.

Comment: For all who did not read the question: I need to convert the 'anystring' to parseBoolean('anystring') so that it returns false. But also need to return true on parseBoolean('anystring') !== false

Comment: @RegisteredUser We all read the question, and tried to help, but what you're asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: if it returns `false`, then it cannot be compared with `!== false` and evaluate to `true`...

Comment: @RegisteredUser: How can `parseBoolean('anystring')` return `false` and also be `!== false`?  I guess `parseBoolean('anystring')` can return `0` or `1`.  `0 == false` AND `0 !== false`.

Comment: This is a pseudo code, where the question is on how to make this work

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. Pseudo-code or not you are still asking for the same value to somehow be both false and not false.

Comment: @nnnnnn You see my logic behind this is that if I take a string 'abc' and check if it is true `if('abc' == true)`, then it is logical to assume that the result should be false, but when I test this it crashes instead of resulting false. Now with this logic if I test `if('abc' !== false)`, it should be true because 'abc' is not a false. Not sure why ppl don't get this....

Comment: Can you please confirm whether you understand the difference between `==` and `===`? And the corresponding difference between `!=` and `!==`? (Have a look at the [MDN page on comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) and pay particular attention to the first four.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Again this is a pseudo code, that 'describes' a 'functionality'... I am sure that you already have a clear understanding of what I need, but doesn't know the answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense in pseudo code. In javascript it kind of "makes sense" because of the (accidental? or intentional?) "loophole" with `==` and `!==`. In pseudo code it clearly reads *equal to false but also not equal to false*. In javascript it reads *kind of equal to false but also not strictly equal to false*.

Comment: `(parseBoolean('this question makes sense') === false) === true`

Comment: @Esailija Why no sense? If it is true return a true, if it is false return false, if it is 'somestring' also return false. Get it?

Comment: I took a stab at rewriting it to describe what I think you're asking. Is that close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this:

> @Esailija Why no sense? If it is true return a true, if it is false
>   return false, if it is 'somestring' also return false. Get it? –
>   Registered User 31 secs ago

You want

```
function parseBoolean(value) {
    return typeof value == "boolean" ? value : false;
}
```

But this obviously won't pass the test of doom.

---

This code passes all your tests:

```
function parseBoolean(bool) {
    return typeof bool == "boolean" ? bool : 0;
}

if( parseBoolean('anystring') == false ) {
    alert("");
}

if( parseBoolean('anystring') !== false ) {
    alert("");
}

if( parseBoolean(true) ) {
    alert('');
}

if( !parseBoolean(false) ) {
    alert('');
}
```

Comment: Amazing. You're my hero. ) This answer has a true spirit of John Skeet. )

Comment: I am gonna tank some downvotes and delete it but it was fun :P

Comment: +1. In my opinion this is the only way the question could be interpreted as making any kind of sense. (But it seems to me if the OP genuinely understands the difference between `!=` and `!==` then they should've been able to come up with this for themselves.)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was possible! Where are now all the skeptics/critics... NM my comment to you in the OP, I was just trying to simplify the requirements so that ppl don't freak out.

Comment: @RegisteredUser just to be clear, neither of the snippets are what you described to want. The first snippet doesn't pass the `equal to false but also not equal to false`-test. The second snippet passes that test but doesn't exactly `return false`, because if it did, it would be impossible to pass the first 2 tests. It's kind of a paradox. But happy to help.

Comment: @Esailija Not sure what you mean, but the code blow the "This code passes all your tests:" is exactly what I want and IMO was very clear about it in my question. The proof of that is the existence of your answer.

Comment: @nnnnnn You had your chance of answering this question, but despite of knowing what !== is, you wasn't able to deliver. It is also doesn't make any sense to expect from someone who has posted a question on SO, to 'come up with an answer himself' as you have put it.

Comment: @RegisteredUser - I asked you explicitly if this was about `==` versus `===` (or `!=` versus `!==`) and you replied to me without answering that point. You kept talking about "returning true", and in one edit of your question your pseudo-code `parseBoolean()` function explicitly returned only `true` or `false` which it turns out is not what you actually want. Even your latest edit still says `parseBoolean('anystring')` should return false. Given that `'anystring'` could reasonably be interpreted as included the empty string your requirement is _still_ unclear.

Comment: @nnnnnn All what you describe is true, but it is the result of all you not understanding the original question and me trying to redefine or simplify the requirements. Admit it, you did some serious trolling on the board and was a major source of interference. I am sure you have also voted it down...

Comment: OK, first up let me apologise for any and all offense to you (and everyone else). Secondly, I was sincerely attempting to get you to clarify the requirements, not trolling. Thirdly, if you check the "Votes Cast" section of my user profile you'll see I've _never_ downvoted any question or answer. Finally, I'm genuinely happy you've got an answer you're satisfied with. Best wishes for your future coding.

Answer (score 2):

What constitutes false? If I had to convert strings to boolean, I would reference a table of strings which should be converted to false.

```
var falsableStrings = {
    "fff": true,
    "false": true
}

function isFalseString(str) {
    return ! falsableStrings[str.toLowerCase()]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8dEF/

Another way would be use use a RegEx:

```
function isFalseString(str) {
    return ! (str == "" || str.match("(fff|false)"))
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8dEF/2/

Comment: Thanks! I have Updated the op whit more details.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you're looking for?

```
var parseBooleanGenerator = function(aPerfectString) {
  return function(someStringFromWild) { 
    return aPerfectString === someStringFromWild 
  };
};

var goodString = 'FFF';
var badString = 'FfF';

console.log(parseBooleanGenerator('FFF')(goodString)); // true
console.log(parseBooleanGenerator('FFF')(badString)); // false
```

... or ...

```
var checkForFFF = parseBooleanGenerator('FFF');
console.log(checkForFFF(goodString)); // true
console.log(checkForFFF(badString)); // false
```

Comment: Huh?  What does this do?

Comment: As the OP didn't state what string should be any string checked against, I gave him a universal solution: a function which takes a single param - a test string - and generates another function that will compare any string given as param to this test string. Is it so complicated? )

Comment: Your code is straightforward for experienced JS coders, but SO is frequented by people just starting out so a full explanation directly in your answer wouldn't have hurt. I can't think of a way to put this that isn't condescending to the OP, so my apologies, but given the confused question I don't think they'll understand this answer.

Comment: No but the actual problem the OP has, ( for `false` to evaluate to `false` and `true` at the same time ), is very complicated

Comment: Thanks! I have Updated the op whit more details.